# Listen for changes to NSTextView with NSTextViewDelegate & textViewDidChange not working

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I want a function to fire every time the user makes a change to my NSTextView. I got this to work in an iOS app and am now trying to make it work in an **OS X** app. I created an outlet for my NSTextView and wrote the following Swift code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textViewOutlet: NSTextView!

    func textViewDidChange(textView: NSTextView) {
        print("Text view changed!")
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors but my statement doesn't print.

Comment: `textViewDidChange` is not a method of `NSTextViewDelegate` or `NSTextDelegate`. Try `textDidChange`.

Comment: @Willeke When I try textDidChange I get an error saying "Objective-C method 'textDidChange:' provided by method 'textDidChange' conflicts with optional requirement method 'textDidChange' in protocol 'NSTextDelegate'"

Comment: Did you change the parameter?

Comment: @Willeke Change the parameter? I just replaced textViewDidChange with textDidChange.

Comment: Same here. None of the answers give a result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be textDidChange(notification:). Try like this:

```
func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else { return }
    print(textView.string)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be why there is no delegate assignment.

```
TextViewOutlet.delegate = self;
```

And the method actually looks like this. Notice the parameters

```
func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

}
```

Comment: The delegate can be set through storybook as well

Comment: I meant storyboard